# logging to production inside a delayed function rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am trying to output to the production log some logging that's happening in a function to which delay is being called on via delayed_job.

Example:

My controller

```
def create_something
  @user = User.find(1)
  @user.delay.do_something_crazy
end
```

My Model

```
def do_something_crazy
  # some code
  Rails.logger.info "Doing something crazy right now!"
end
```

The logging is not being output into my production log. Without delay, it does but with it seems to not?

Comment: See the docs https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/wiki

Comment: As suggested, using `Delayed::Worker.logger.debug("TESTING")` in the function that is put into delay will output in the delayed_job log which I setup. Is there a way to merge with production?

Comment: Also, @Gene, this works in development env and I can see the logs even within delayed_job, but in production it doesn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add initializer file `delayed_jobs_settings.rb` to `config/initializers` (unless you already have something like this for Delayed Jobs settings) and add this code:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', 'dj.log'))
```

And it will save it to `log/dj.log`.

Or just

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
```

for logging to default Rails log.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use `Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger`  in delayed job gem from https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job ?

Comment: @SatriaJanaka yes - https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/5ac5adea8d18325d0470eeebfa81227b1f5961e3/lib/delayed/railtie.rb#L7

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I already tried that, but the delayed job is still not logging in my Openshift log? I have the detail of the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509166/is-it-possible-to-write-delayed-jobs-log-to-log-in-openshift-pod/71533153#71533153