# Is it possible to write delayed_jobs.log to log in Openshift pod?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kubernetes, openshift, kibana

The application that me and my team working on use Ruby on Rails hosted in Openshift pod. We use delayed_job to handle background process, and for delayed_job logging, the application write the log into `log/delayed_job.log` file. However, if a new pod for the application is created, the pod will create a new file. Also, the company is using Kibana to save every log from Openshift pod.

What we tried so far is put this code in `delayed_job_config.rb`

`Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)`

To write the log for another process beside delayed job, in order to write the log in Openshift pod log, we use this following code, e.g:

`Rails.logger.info "Result: #{ldap.get_operation_result.code}"`

However, the delayed_job log is not still appear in Logs tab of the pod (in order for the log to appear in Kibana)

The goal is to write the log in Logs tab of the Openshift pod.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE :

We tried to put `Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger` in `delayed_job_config.rb` but still did not work

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help anyone:

We're ended up muting the DelayedJobs ActiveRecord related logs
playing around [this delayed_job repo post](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/477#issuecomment-800341818) to also ensure that if an error occurs, we get the previous log level back

And within our container, we tail the actual delayed job log file to output to get the actual jobs log

> tail -f /app/log/production.log &

It's not optimal, but at least, we get to see the logs!

Answer (score 0):

In general everything written to STDOUT or STDERR from the main process of the container/pod is appearing in the log tab. I guess you problem will be that your background work is not executed in the main process and therefore not shown in the log tab.

As an example we had an application where the start script was executing the actual work in another process. Even though this new process logged to STDOUT it will not appear in the log tab as OpenShift only shows the logs of the main process which was in our case the process executing the script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is the screenshoot of  `ps aux`  in the pod : https://imgur.com/a/k0qhrCo. I think the delayed_job process is not the main process of the pod?. The delayed_job process and the app main process are in the same pod. So it leads me to a new question, is it possible to write the log in the pod log, although my delayed_job process is not the main process of the pod?